How can DUAL be used for something other than calculating an equation?
I am trying to understand how DUAL, which from my understanding, is used to calculate an equation (SELECT (4+3) FROM DUAL;), can be used create a table as well. Given these two tables, "Items" and "Items_Related":
Items:



Item_Number




24-1


24-2


24-3


24-4


24-5



Items_Related:



Master_Item
Related_Item




24-1
24-2


24-1
24-3


24-1
24-4


24-1
24-5


24-2
24-1


24-3
24-1


24-4
24-1


24-5
24-1



How can the following query:
SELECT
ITEMS.ITEM_NUMBER,
(SELECT DATABASE.ROWS_TO_HTML (SELECT RELATED_ITEM || FROM ITEMS_RELATED || WHERE ITEMS_RELATED.MASTER_ITEM = ``` || ITEMS.ITEM_NUMBER || ```` || `` || ORDER BY ITEMS_RELATED.RELATED_ITEM`) FROM DUAL) AS RELATED_ITEM
FROM ITEMS
;
create this table, where 24-1 in the ITEM_NUMBER field is one merged cell when the table is exported as an Excel spreadsheet, and the rest are all separate:



ITEM_NUMBER
RELATED_ITEM




24-1
24-2



24-3



24-4



24-5


24-2
24-1


24-3
24-1


24-4
24-1


24-5
24-1



When I tried to input a test query into oracle SQL developer, such as:
SELECT ('SELECT ITEM_NUMBER' || 'FROM ITEMS') FROM DUAL;
the result was:
'SELECT ITEM_NUMBER.....
SELECT ITEM_NUMBERFROM ITEMS

DUAL is a pseudo-table. It cannot do anything. It's a substitute for not having an actual table when you want to do something to test, such as a calculation or concatenation, or retrieve a system value such as the date. If you need an actual table, you can either create one or use a temp table. Your query works just fine when you know what DUAL means. It's returning the concatenation of the two strings SELECT ITEM NUMBER and FROM ITEMS.

You should generally avoid the DUAL table if not absolutely required. That's a strange, unlucky Oracle-relict which no other RDBMS has. And from Oracle 23c on, you finally don't need it anymore.

I am not sure if you really need DUAL, I think you can utilise the two tables ITEMS and ITEMS_RELATED and get the required output, let us know.
Fiddle
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ir.MASTER_ITEM ORDER BY ir.RELATED_ITEM) = 1
        THEN ir.MASTER_ITEM
        ELSE NULL
    END AS ITEM_NUMBER,
    ir.RELATED_ITEM
FROM 
    ITEMS_RELATED ir
JOIN 
    ITEMS i
    ON ir.MASTER_ITEM = i.ITEM_NUMBER
ORDER BY 
    ir.MASTER_ITEM, ir.RELATED_ITEM;

Output

